# Modify Properties inside a Style programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, setter

I've got the following style defined in the resources of a UserControl:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Width="40" Height="40" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="3">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="#666666" />
    <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Button.Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#666666" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For example I use it like the following:

```
<Button Click="Toolbar_DocumentMarkup_Click" Name="BtnUnderline" Margin="10,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource MenuItemButton}">
    <fa:FontAwesome VerticalAlignment="Center" Icon="Underline" FontSize="24"/>
</Button>
```

I need to set the border's width and the height programmatically from the code behind so that the view will be updated on runtime.

**What I tried so far**:

Access the style through the Resources:

```
var style = Resources["MenuItemButton"] as Style
```

but I can't find the right properties in this style object.

**Another idea:**

Define the width and height as DependencyProperties or implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but I think in my case it's much easier to just set these two values programmatically.

Some oppinions or suggestions on this problem?

Comment: You need to change all width and height of your buttons or just for one of them?

Comment: I'm using the style on many buttons, so all need to be changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your resources:

```
 <sys:Double x:Key="ButtonHeight">200</sys:Double>
 <sys:Double x:Key="ButtonWidth">200</sys:Double>

<Style x:Key="MenuItemButton" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Width="40" Height="40" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="3">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonHeight}" />
<Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonWidth}" />
<Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="#666666" />
<Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="Transparent" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Button.Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#666666" />
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And then in your code behind you change it in your event using:

```
this.Resources["ButtonHeight"] = ...
```

and

```
this.Resources["ButtonWidth"] = ...
```

EDIT: forgot that of course you need to add the path to system

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```